# svg animation - error Cannot read property 'getTotalLength' of null

Tags: javascript, svg

i have made this svg text animation http://jsfiddle.net/thLvLkq0/2/

```
function init(i) {
    path[i] = document.getElementById('path'+i);
    length = path[i].getTotalLength();
    path[i].style.transition = path[i].style.WebkitTransition = 'none';

    length[i] = length;
    path[i].style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    path[i].style.strokeDashoffset = length;

    path[i].getBoundingClientRect();
}
```

chrome browser returns this error message `Cannot read property 'getTotalLength' of null`

is there any way to solve it? i can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this because it's looking for an element with the id of `path3`, however you only have `path1` and `path2`. You can stop the for loop by changing `for(var i=1; i<=3; i++)` to `for(var i=1; i<3; i++)`.

Comment: console.log is your friend :)